# How to reduce the length and width of the search bar in my website?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My website is built on WordPress and I use `ivory` search plugin for the search bar on my website. My website is `www.osdoc.in`.

I want to reduce the length and breadth of the search bar because it is pushing menu icons towards the website logo.

Comment: https://themeisle.com/blog/css-in-wordpress/
 There can you add some css to customise your search bar

Comment: I know where to add the css but dont know the code to to put that will do the above work. I am not a coding guy so thats why i need help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is some css code to modify the search bar :

```
   .woocommerce input[type=search] {
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
}
```